# How can Java code check for the number of floating point registers?

Tags: java, android, cpu-registers, neon

We have a native library (a whole game engine and game code) that is built in two distinct versions. One version that supports armeabi-v7a with 32 floating point registers and Neon SIMD instructions and another version that supports armeabi-v7a with 16 floating point registers (to use on e.g. Tegra 2 devices) and therefore not use Neon SIMD instructions since that wouldn't work.

When our game starts, we are in Java land to do some setup and then load the correct library. Now, how do I find out which library to load? One solution would be to add yet another native library except the two mentioned above, that only has a method to call over JNI to check for hardware support using the NDK... but surely, there must be a way to check this from Java?

I tried printing everything found in the android.os.Build class and got these but I cannot see what to use here:

```
BOARD: EeePad
BOOTLOADER: unknown
BRAND: asus
CPU_ABI: armeabi-v7a
CPU_ABI2: armeabi
DEVICE: TF101
DISPLAY: IML74K.WW_epad-9.2.1.27-20120615
FINGERPRINT: asus/WW_epad/TF101:4.0.3/IML74K/WW_epad-9.2.1.27-20120615:user/release-keys
HARDWARE: ventana
HOST: Mars
ID: IML74K
MANUFACTURER: asus
MODEL: Transformer TF101
PRODUCT: WW_epad
RADIO: unknown
SERIAL: 037c708543204317
TAGS: release-keys
TYPE: user
USER: unknown
```

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like you will have to add another native lib to check for hardware support. Check out the hello-neon example: https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/ndk/samples/hello-neon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to read [/proc/cpuinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc), which should contain a line `Features :` telling you about the capabilities of the core you are on.

For example on my Xperia Z1 it shows:

```
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt
```

It should be easy to process contents of that line from Android / Java layer..

This is also what `NDK` does when you call [android_getCpuFeatures()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/master/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c).

Comment: I ended up using some code from pi4j, which is a Java implementation for Raspberry Pie. It did just what you are proposing and it worked just fine. http://pi4j.com/